# An individual's death reason

Tags: phrase-request

Please suppose someone has died very suspiciously an police have fallen into doubt if it was a murder. Does the bold part of the following self-made sentence sound natural to you:

> - The police are investigating that **individual’s death reason.**

For me, it works. I would be thankful if someone could let me know whether there is a more natural way of expressing the structure "an individual's death reason".

Comment: I'd say, "The police is investigating the reason behind the death of that individual."

Comment: @SovereignSun isn't it too wordy? :/ Oching dlingi. Mne nada chyt po carochi. ;)

Comment: "has died" not "has been died".  **To die** is intransitive.  Also, **have fallen**.

Comment: "death reason" isn't idiomatic English, but people might think it means "...investigating why that individual committed suicide".

Answer (score 8):

The expression most often used in police reports and media coverage is:

> Police are investigating **the cause of death.**

Another common expression when talking about a broader police investigation would be

> Police are investigating **the circumstances surrounding the death**.

The first expression means "what specifically killed the person," e.g. a gunshot. The second expression would mean, for example, they are wondering what the person was doing in that part of town and who they had spoken to.

Comment: It is obvious @user34259, but how we can indicate that we are talking about a particular individual? :)

Comment: @A-friend It's simply *the cause of death of Mr. X*.

Comment: +1 to 34258. Or "the cause of death of *the deceased*".

Comment: @DamkerngT. I was wondering if someone could just let me know what was wrong with my original sentence?

Comment: @A-friend - "An individual's death reason" just is not something we normally say; it isn't idiomatic.  As for how we know that we're talking about a particular individual: context.  After all, we are not usually talking about the cause of all death!

Comment: One could write _he cause of death in this case._ But if the preceding text has recently mentioned the fact that some individual has died, _in this case_ might be redundant; while if the preceding text has _not_ mentioned any such thing, who is "that individual"?

Comment: @DamkerngT. That would count as a nasal release (sorry, don't have chat at the moment ..)! (I think :))